# can we arrange grid.draw output into a single plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

Is there a method where we can arrange multiple `grid.draw` output into a single plot.

I have multiple `grid.draw` outputs as shown below.

```
g <- ggplotGrob(p1)
g <- gtable_add_grob(g, rasterGrob(img,width=unit(3,"cm"),x =     
                     unit(49,"cm")),t=2.5,l=1,b=1,r=5,z=Inf)
     grid.newpage()
     grid.draw(g)


g1 <- ggplotGrob(p2)
g1 <- gtable_add_grob(g1, rasterGrob(img,width=unit(3,"cm"),x =     
                     unit(49,"cm")),t=2.5,l=1,b=1,r=5,z=Inf)
     grid.newpage()
     grid.draw(g1)


g2 <- ggplotGrob(p2)
g2 <- gtable_add_grob(g2, rasterGrob(img,width=unit(3,"cm"),x =     
                     unit(49,"cm")),t=2.5,l=1,b=1,r=5,z=Inf)
     grid.newpage()
     grid.draw(g2)


g3 <- ggplotGrob(p3)
g3 <- gtable_add_grob(g3, rasterGrob(img,width=unit(3,"cm"),x =     
                     unit(49,"cm")),t=2.5,l=1,b=1,r=5,z=Inf)
     grid.newpage()
     grid.draw(g3)
```

I tried `grid.arrange` but got an `Error saying object g1 not found`.

I used the below code.

```
grid.arrange(grid.draw(g1),grid.draw(g2),grid.draw(g3),ncol=2)
```

Comment: if you look at the code `grid.arrange` is `grid.draw(arrangeGrob(...`, so just try `grid.arrange(g,, g1, g2, g3, ncol=2)`. Are you sure you want an image at `49cm`, and is the layout correct?

Comment: Thanks for the support  @user20650 . Yes the layout is looking good as well.